# Can I install two thermostats on one furnace/act unit? I will be using one in living room, the other in a hallway

Tags: heating, thermostat, cooling

The reason is that there is a gas fireplace(stove) in the living room that has the pilot on all year. Currently the thermostat is in the hall keeping the back of the house cool. The heat from the fireplace pilot keeps the living room too warm so I want to control the ac unit from the living room in the summer and the heat from the hall in the winter. I am using nest thermostats

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. My guess is this might work with "dumb" thermostats, but the Nest units would be too intelligent and would get totally confused.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cheaper to just turn the darn gas off to the pilot during the summer??

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest looking for a thermostat that supports remote sensors. I personally own [ecobees](http://www.ecobee.com) which support up to 64 wireless sensors per unit. You can decide which of the sensors participate in measuring the average temperature for each time slot of the day. I believe Honeywell offers thermostats that support sensors as well in both the wired and wireless variety.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple and cheap single double pole switch. In 1 position the system would use the hall thermostat in the other position the system would use the living room thermostat. The switch can be a very inexpensive one (spdt) with the common going to the furnace and the NO normally open to one. Then the NC normally closed to the other thermostat the system would chose the thermostat based on the switch position. If you have a higher end system a double pole switch may be required with the heat on one pole and the cooling on the other pole but both wired the same with NO, NC and common going back to the furnace / AC control.

Comment: I might add there are also 4PDT and 6PDT switches which simplify the question of which wires need to be switched.

Comment: Where can I get a 6PDT switch.

Comment: Look on line they are not cheap but you only need a low voltage one